# Making delay() work with a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, delay, settimeout

I have a small plugin for setting the height of an element, based on several variable factors. On the page load, I wanted a delay in order to prevent the height from being set for a number of seconds. I know delay only works on effects, is there a way I can register my plugin as an effect, or do I need to do this another way?

Desire launch code:

```
$(".app_advert").delay(10000).set_height(2000);
```

Plugin Code:

```
       //SetHeight plugin
    (function($){
        $.fn.extend({
            set_height: function(time, callback){
                    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                    win_height = $(window).height();
                    document_height = $(document).height();


                    footer_height = $('#footer').height();
                    footer_offset = (document_height-(win_height+scroll));
                    footer_remainder = footer_height-footer_offset;

                return this.each(function(){
                    var x = $(this);

                    if(footer_height-footer_offset<=0){
                        height = 0;
                    } else {
                        height = footer_height-footer_offset;
                    }
                    $(x).stop(true, false).animate({bottom: height}, time, function(){
                        if (callback && typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                                callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
                            }

                    });
                });
            }
        });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to invoke jQuerys `.queue()` manually. Could look like;

```
$(".app_advert").delay(10000).queue(function() {
    $(this).set_height(2000);
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

You can even chain more queued methods on that construct behind. Beware, all `fx methods` are queued by default for any other method you want to apply to the current wrapped set, invoke another `.queue()`.

Have a read: http://api.jquery.com/queue

Comment: could I add this into my plugin code? If so, any pointers on how

Comment: @MildFuzz: yes of course you can. Just put it in there just like that.

Comment: I just wrapped the queue method around the animation in my plugin, and the delay (which is triggered externally) seems to work just fine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

how about using setTimeout inside your plugin. Or even better write your own delay plugin using setTimeout using a dummy method, so that you can chain your events.